# SQL How to make this sargeable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this `WHERE` clause that I believe to not be sargeable:

```
WHERE (CAST((100 - ((db_one.Field1 / db_two.Field2) * 100)) AS UNSIGNED)) < 80
```

How do I make this sargeable?

Comment: `select
1
where (CAST((100 - ((db_one.Field1 / db_two.Field2) * 100)) AS INT) ) < 80`

Comment: There really isn't a way to make this sargable directly in your where clause. It will have to calculate the formula for every single row.

Comment: You can simplify your expression to bring it in form `filed = some expression with other field` If there is big difference between size in this table use big table from left.

Comment: As I know SQL Server not support unsigned datatype.